# how to measure code coverage by junit test with sonar for non maven project

Tags: junit, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

I have scanned my project with the help of sonar runner and sonar qube, but in the results i am not able to see the coverage details and test cases details. can any one tell me the process for code coverage with sonar for a non maven project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have worked extensively on sonar so i could help you out. But your requirement is not clear. Can you let me know what is the problem your facing. Have you check localhost:9000 for the results. In case you want ot login username and password are admin/admin

Comment: i have opened localhost:9000, there i can see issues and lines of code etc. but i am not able to see the coverage details(Example:Line coverage ,Condition coverage ,Unit tests success (%) ) those fields are empty

Comment: do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: Hi ravi kiran..i have installed eclemma but it is not generating coverage.xml. it is directly showing results

Comment: Hi Sorry, my business hours had started so was quite busy. THis is my email add, you can drop me a mail there kirankumar.15789@gmail.com. In eclemma we have an option export session , can you use that and export it  this is the guide http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ECLEMMA is a great coverage plugin for eclipse 
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclemma-java-code-coverage

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube doesnt inbuit give you code coverage, it only detects code violations. Kindly use plugins like emma, cobertura, jacoco to generate these details. You can configure these plugins to get the reports displayed on sonarqube server

Comment: thank you. can you tell me which plug in i have to use for a non maven project? and tell me how to use it also.

Comment: are you using Ant for your build or Gradle if it is not maven

Comment: in one project we are using Ant, and in another project we are not using any build tool

Comment: For ant build , just check out how to configure Jacoco plugin into the script , below link can throw you some light.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211584/ant-sonar-0-code-coverage also if there is no build tool , kindly install eclipse plugin EclEmma or eCobertura, right click on the project and select over Cover As , this will generate coverage.xml file which will be picked by sonar to display you the results.

Comment: Hi ravi kiran..i have installed eclemma but it is not generating coverage.xml. it is directly showing results

Comment: Hi Ravi. I need response from you.